# Drawing a circle subdivided into arcs of different colors

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I would like to draw a circle and have different parts in different colors. Which part has which color should be changeable with sliders.

I've managed to do two colors, but would like to have three or four.

```
Manipulate[Show[
  Graphics[{Circle[], {Black, PointSize@.04, Point@{Cos[Pi/2], Sin[Pi/2]}}}],
  Graphics[{Circle[], {Black, PointSize@.04, Point@{Cos[3 Pi/2], Sin[3 Pi/2]}}}],
  Graphics[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[1], Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}],
  Graphics[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[4], Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0 Degree, 360 Degree}]}],
  Graphics[{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[4], Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {r Degree, l Degree}]}],
  PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}}, 
  ImageSize -> 250], 
  {{l, 180, "L"}, r, 360 + r}, 
  {{r, 0, "R"}, l - 360, l}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Take a look at `TrackingFunction`. You need to decide which parts are reduced when other changes.

Comment: Something like: n = 5
dph = 2 Pi/n;
Graphics[{Thickness[0.05], 
  Table[{Hue[1/i], Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {(i - 1) dph, i dph}]}, {i, n}]}]

Answer (score 11):

```
Manipulate[
 With[{arc = Arrow@Table[AngleVector[t], {t, If[# < #2, #, # - 2 Pi], #2, .005}] &},
  Graphics[{
    Thick, 
    Riffle[{Red, Green, Blue, Yellow}, arc@@@Partition[Mod[ArcTan@@@pt, 2 Pi], 2, 1, 1]]
    }, PlotRange -> 1.2]
  ],
  {{pt, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> (Do[pt[[i]] = Normalize[#[[i]]], {i, 4}]; &)}
 ]
```

[image]

Another way, compatibility with prior versions

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}, arc},
  arc = Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {If[# < #2, #, # - 2 Pi], #2}] &;
  Graphics[{
    Thick, Dynamic@Riffle[{Red, Green, Blue, Yellow}, 
      arc@@@Partition[Mod[ArcTan@@@pt, 2 Pi], 2, 1, 1]],
    Array[Function[i, Locator[Dynamic[pt[[i]], (pt[[i]] = Normalize[#]) &]]], 4]
    }, PlotRange->1.2
   ]
  ] // Deploy
```

Answer (score 7):

```
circle[t_] = {Cos[2 Pi*t], Sin[2 Pi*t]};
plotArc[{tmin_, tmax_}, color_] := 
 ParametricPlot[circle[t], {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotStyle -> color]
Show[plotArc[{0., 0.3}, Blue], plotArc[{0.3, 0.5}, Red], 
 plotArc[{0.5, 0.8}, Green], plotArc[{0.8, 1}, Orange], 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

Wrapped in a function that you can use with `Manipulate`:

```
plotCircle[ts_, colors_] := 
 With[{ts2 = ts~Join~{1 + ts[[1]]}}, 
  Show[Table[
    plotArc[{ts2[[i]], ts2[[i + 1]]}, colors[[i]]], {i, 1, 
     Length[ts]}], PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]]
```

Example:

```
plotCircle[{0.2, 0.5, 0.8}, {Blue, Green, Red}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use a single `ParametricPlot` with the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) to get circular arcs:

```
SeedRandom[1]
mesh = RandomSample[Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50], 5];

ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]},{t, 0 , 2 Pi},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {mesh}, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[0],
 MeshShading -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@mesh]), 
 PlotRange -> ({{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}),
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[7]], 
 Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize[12], Black, Point[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}]
```

[image]